# Setting VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing in a Windows 8.1 Store App

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I have a XAML page in a Windows 8.1 Store App. I set the data context for a ListView but I initially have it collapsed. What I am trying to do is toggle the visibility of some of the elements in the ListView before making it visible. But it doesn't load them unless it becomes visible. So, to forced it to load the items, I am trying to set "IsVirtualizing" to false so that I don't have to worry about it (and I don't mind the hit in performance since I won't have that many items). But for all the examples I look at, all I get is

```
The property "IsVirtualizing" does not have an accessible setter.
```

Not sure what is going on here.

Here is the relevant piece of code with the other contents stripped out.

```
<common:LayoutAwarePage
    x:Class="FlashMe.DeckView"
    DataContext="{Binding DefaultViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:FlashMe"
    xmlns:common="using:FlashMe.Common"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    >


        <ScrollViewer x:Name="deckScrollViewer" Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Margin="0,15,0,0">
            <StackPanel x:Name="deckStackPanel" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Grid Width="100" x:Name="MarginBuffer" />
                <ListView x:Name="cardsListViewDisplay" Visibility="Collapsed" SelectionMode="None" Width="500" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FlashCardsAsList}" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Border>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="490" Height="400" RightTapped="FlashCardRightClicked">
                                    <Grid Width="490" Height="200" Background="Gainsboro">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Front}"
                                                   Foreground="Black" 
                                                   Style="{StaticResource GroupHeaderTextStyle}"
                                                   Margin="4,0,4,4"
                                                   FontWeight="SemiBold"
                                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                   TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                                   MaxWidth="410"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <Grid Width="500" Height="200" Background="{Binding ElementName=deckStackPanel, Path=DataContext.DeckColorBrush}">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Back}"
                                                   Foreground="White" 
                                                   Style="{StaticResource GroupHeaderTextStyle}"
                                                   Margin="4,0,0,4"   
                                                   FontWeight="SemiBold"
                                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                                   TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                                   MaxWidth="410"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Border>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
</common:LayoutAwarePage>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows Store Apps, the `IsVirtualizing` property is read-only.

From the Remarks section on the [VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizingProperty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.virtualizingstackpanel.isvirtualizingproperty.aspx) page on MSDN:

> **VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing** is an atypical attached property
>   because it does not have a **Set** accessor, and thus is not really a XAML
>   attached property with a markup usage. Instead,
>   **VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing** functions as a sentinel whereby
>   child elements can query the **VirtualizingStackPanel** parent, and
>   determine whether virtualization is being used. ...

Comment: I completely missed that section while reading the MSDN page. Thanks!